# Assumptions for 2d simplification of Navier-Stokes flow

Tags: simulations, navier-stokes

There are many cases where Navier-Stokes flow is simplified to a two-dimensional problem to reduce the costs for a numerical simulation, e.g., flow around an airfoil, channel flow or pipe flow.

To allow this simplification from three to two dimensions, in the ignored dimension any influence like boundaries must be far enough away. Or there are some kind of symmetry.

These assumptions are seldom explicitly stated. Which conditions must be fulfilled, to justify a two-dimensional Navier-Stokes flow? Are there some rules of thumb, maybe depending on the Reynolds number?

Answer (score 3):

The only assumption required is that the variation in properties in the 3rd direction are much smaller than the variation in properties in the remaining 2 directions. Likewise, reducing to 1D equations requires assuming that variations in the other 2 are small relative to the remaining dimension.

The usual approach is to non-dimensionalize the equations by some reference values and then retaining terms that are of leading order. So for 2D flows, you would usually pick a reference velocity in one direction, call it $U_\infty$. When you go through non-dimensionalizing things, you will end up with $u/U_\infty$, $v/U_\infty$, and $w/U_\infty$. Then $u/U_\infty \approx O(1)$, $v/U_\infty \approx O(1)$ (for 2D) or $v/U_\infty \ll 1$ (for 1D), and $w/U_\infty \ll 1$ for 1D or 2D.

Comment: Do you know a citable source explaining or at least using this? Preferable in the context of fluid mechanics?

Comment: @usr1234567 I'll have to check for which books have it. I know we spent a lot of time on the topic in our viscous fluid flows class in grad school, but I don't know if it was covered in a book or if it was just constantly drilled into us during lectures.